# filling up a time sheet on excel

Tags: windows-xp

I am trying to build a time sheet in a manner where I only need to put the time in and time out, and it would calculate the overtime, differential and other penalties.

Using 06:00 AM or PM, I am forced to leave one space between :00 and AM or PM, else the input is a failure. I am sick of always have to input the colons and spaces.

I want instead, to be able to just input 6A or 6P and get automatically converted into 06:00 AM or 6:00 PM on the time sheet.

Can you guys help?

Thank you,

Italo
(Sorry for the re-editing)

Comment: Can they just use 6AM or 6PM?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Custom formats in Excel that will eliminate the need for the space between :00 and the AM or PM but if you use a Custom format that is just hhAM/PM then you will not be able to insert 6:30AM or PM. The only way to be able to put 6A or 6P and have it interpreted correctly is to set up an input column that will "feed" the actual time column based on "If" statements. e.g. If input cell = "6P" then insert "6:00PM" etc in the actual time column. Hope this helps!